# Is there an alternative to the command line "python -m module app ..." that works inside Python code?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, spacy, python-module

For example I'm downloading a model for spaCy using the command:

```bash
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Is there an acceptable way to access this functionality within Python, something like:

```py
import spacy

spacy.download('en_core_web_sm') # or whatever command that would work
```

?

I was also wondering about how to access this functionalities for other cases.

I tried to look directly at spaCy source code but it wasn't clear at all to me how this worked (there seems to be an "app" system of some sort, I have no idea of this works).

Comment: Depends on the module.  The conventional way would be to import it into your Python script since `-m` is only applicable from a command-line perspective, but if that's the *only* thing that spaCy provides to you, you may have an uphill battle in getting the right things into your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the same functionality within a script using `spacy.cli.download`. It is essentially an internal call to `pip`. For example:

```
import spacy
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")
# lots of output from pip as model is installed
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
...
```

Please note that this is specific to spaCy. Other modules that are run via the command line - `python -m some_module command ...` won't necessarily have the `command` functionality exposed in exactly this way.